# How to install touch backend if user is using a mobile?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I want to use the React DnD library and I want to support desktop and mobile. How can I switch the back end to HTML 5 or Touch at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-multi-backend.
This stuff can help you use different DND backends depending on an environment where you use it.